# Compile a single standalone file in visual studio via its command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I simply would like to check if my standalone file compiles.

This by using the in-build Visual Studio (2020) command line.

My File ('MyFile.cpp') is open in visual studio tabs.

Must say that I do have a project loaded already to Visual Studio, this file i want to check is irrelevant to this project.

I tried different things, but it always ended up compiling my entire project and not my file.

I do not wish to create a project for that file.

Is there a command i can run in command line of visual studio?? something like "CompileOnly MyFile.c"?

That will compile it using same method as it compiles the entire project.

Comment: There's the "Compile" Command on the Build menu that will compile just the current source file.

Comment: If you have file open in the tab of VS2019, hit Ctrl-F7, it will start single file compilation

Answer (score 1):

The command for compiling a single file is `cl MyFile.c`, this requires the file to have all the resources it needs to compile by itself.